# Can I use the phone's mic when connected to a bluetooth speaker?

Tags: audio, microphone, bluetooth-audio

When connecting the phone to a BT speaker that includes a mic (pretty much all of them), the speaker acts like a BT headset, and the phone's mic is disabled.

Can I use the speaker for audio output only, using the phone's internal mic?

Update: Think about handling a phone call using the BT speaker, but its mic is lousy and noisy, so I want to use the internal phone mic instead.

Comment: If you have the BT, the best thing would be to test

Comment: @Beveloper - ... and how should I test that???

Comment: you asked: Can I use the speaker for audio output only, using the phone's internal mic? your post sounded like you did connect the speaker but the mic is disabled. So to test if the internal mic works is to use a sound recorder on your phone to check that

Comment: @Beveloper - re-reading my post, I do not see why you understood that the mic is disabled. My question is - how to disable the external (remote) mic and use the internal mic instead, while still being connected to the remote speaker for audio output. See update.

Comment: Okay. Lets see if this works: Go to your phone Bluetooth setting, from the list of paired devices, select the configuration button on the right of the BT Speaker. There's always options to select "functionality" which can be marked on or off. Check if you'll see a Mic option there and deselect it...

Comment: How the person's voice will be head over the speaker

Comment: @Beveloper - OK that was a good idea. I checked the phone BT setting for the speaker device. You can configure it to pair as a phone device or as a media device. So I disabled the "phone" setting and tried calling. The problem is that now it won't connect for phone calls at all. So, no luck here.

Comment: sorry about that. Wish I could assist futher. I guess you may have to disconnect the speaker when making calls then